# Hyperledger Fabric Java rich query on an asset

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

i need help with the getQueryResult() function in hyperledger fabric.
I know that i can use it this way:

```
    String queryHash;
QueryResultsIterator<KeyValue> results = stub.getQueryResult("{\"selector\":{\"hash\":\"" + queryHash + "\"}}");
```

to run a query that searches each asset for those with the hash parameter set to the queryHash string.
At the moment, however, I have 3 different type of assets and I would like to understand how to set the search on only one of them.

Let me explain. Let us suppose that I have 3 different types of assets. For example, an asset called a car, with its attributes (id, name, model, etc.), an asset called a truck, also with its attributes, and another called an aeroplane, also with its attributes.
Let's say I want to make a query that searches for all the cars by make, but without including trucks and planes.
How can I indicate in the query that I am referring only to that type of asset?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why querying on a single object?

I don't know about your chaincode models, but supposing you have some kind of ID, it would be something like:

```java
String id;
String queryHash;
// ...
QueryResultsIterator<KeyValue> results = stub.getQueryResult("{\"selector\":{\"id\":\"" + id + "\"" + ", " + "\"hash\":\"" + queryHash + "\" }}");
```

If you have access to its CouchDB key, you can simply get the object and check the hash when deserialized:

```java
String couchdbKey;
// ...
byte[] ba = stub.getState​(couchdbKey);
// Deserialize ba and check hash
```

---

**EDIT**

I think you should refactor your models. I usually develop chaincodes in Go, but in Java it could be something like (check the code, it is written on the fly):

```java
public abstract class Asset {

    @Property()
    private String doctype;

    @Property()
    private String id;

    protected Asset(String doctype) {
        this.doctype = doctype;
    }

    public String getDoctype() {
        return doctype;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // ...
}

@DataType()
public class Car extends Asset {
    public static final String DOCTYPE = "car";

    public Car() {
        super(Car.DOCTYPE);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then, you can query on `doctype` for each model. And you should preferably create an index for `doctype`.

Comment: I must have misunderstood. I have 3 different types of assets. For example, an asset called a car, with its attributes (id, name, model, etc.), an asset called a truck, also with its attributes, and another called an aeroplane, also with its attributes.
Let's say I want to make a query that searches for all the cars by make, but without including trucks and planes. 
How can I indicate in the query that I am referring only to that type of asset?

Comment: Then, take my 1st example and replace "id" with "docType" or something like that. You should have that kind of field in all your models (in an abstract parent class, for instance) if you manage different models. You should also define a CouchDB index for that field, as it would be commonly used in queries.

Comment: Take a look at my edit.